# Augmented reality with swift (something like Flightradar24)

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, avcapturesession

I'm creating an app, that could spot people using iBeacon technology. So now i want to create a feature to show people that are near me using iPhone camera. Basically it should look like FlightRadar24 app function, that draw airplane names above video. What should i use to draw something(for example, user avatar, that is near) above camera layer and constantly update it's position?

Comment: You need to provide way more information on what you need to do, what you've tried, code that you've tried, code that hasn't work/worked, steps taken, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you need to do some image recognition. I would check out OpenCV. Best way to download it is downloading the source and compile it locally into a framework that you will drag inside your app. OpenCV is C++, so you will need to create an Objective C wrapper around the functions that you need and import those into Swift via a bridging header. Remember that C++ needs garbage collection. This part is simple on paper but if you never worked with computer vision it gets really difficult to spot which functions you need to "wrap".

Answer (score 2):

Precise 3D location is required before it could be displayed in an augmented reality mode.

I don't think that iBeacon/beacons generally or even raw bluetooth will give you a direction just a distance/proximity based on the power.

Given that I don't think the feature that you are describing is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use an UIView and add it on the top layer of your view hierarchy. I tried it in my own project and this solution is working fine.

Comment: For a more detailed answer I need more details in the question

Answer (score 0):

you can try one of these approaches:

Use a framework written in swift

- https://github.com/DanijelHuis/HDAugmentedReality

use this framework written in Objective-C

- https://github.com/gleue/TGLAugmentedRealityView

or follow this tutorial

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/146436/augmented-reality-ios-tutorial-location-based-2